# Using one Javascript / Jquery function on multiple Html elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, dom

I am using js/jquery to create draggable graph. Graph has two draggable elements that select values on graph based behind. My problem now is that next step would be to be able to **multiply up to six graphs on one page**, which i did, now when graphs are created dynamically, only way to reference element is by `$(this)`, how will adress both elements in same function?

**EDIT:**

```
function drag_function(event, ui) {

    var $selFirst = $(".second :nth-child(1)"),
        $selSecond = $(".second :nth-child(2)"),
        cachedWidth = $selFirst.outerWidth();

    var $firstRightBorder = $selFirst.position().left + 1,
        $secondLeft = $selSecond.position().left,
        diff = $firstRightBorder - $secondLeft;
}
```

If I use :

```
function drag_function(event, ui) {

    var $selFirst = $(this),
        $selSecond = $(this),
        cachedWidth = $selFirst.outerWidth();

    var $firstRightBorder = $selFirst.position().left + 1,
        $secondLeft = $selSecond.position().left,
        diff = $firstRightBorder - $secondLeft;
}
```

also doesnt work??

ANSWER:

```
 var $selFirst = $(this).parent().children().eq(0),
        $selSecond = $(this).parent().children().eq(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is still not clear what you want to achieve. I guess it is this. Please drag and drop the divs in example given below.

http://jsfiddle.net/diode/8wxCb/1/

In event handler functions `this` and `event.currentTarget` will refer to the object for which the event has occurred.

for e.g:

```
button1.onclick = function(event){

     console.log(this);  // button1
     console.log(event.currentTarget);  // button1

}
```

So if you add same function as listener to many, in the function you can check

```
if(this == button1){

}else if(this == button2){

}
```

or

```
if(this.id == "button1"){

}else if(this.id == "button2"){

}
```

As you get the object inside the function you can directly read/write it's properties

see: http://jsfiddle.net/diode/nZQy6/

Comment: just to add, all elements in this component are created dynamical and can be removed, so I cannot go a say If "button1"... because the user can add/remove, ID names are constructed dynamically?